# How to display results from a data table with an encrypted user id?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, php, database, mysql

I'm trying to display a table of results for particular users who have submitted answers to quizzes. The problem is that the mysql database I am working with has a funky value for the user's ID.

I'm working off of the plugin [WP Simple Survey](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-simple-survey/), which allows the admin to create a number of surveys and weight answers with "points." The only data table that has a unique value for the user's id is "submitter_id," but the format is not the regular WP user id expressed as a number. Instead it looks like this:

**wpss_4fc2636f6814a**

I need a way to translate this to a typical user_id or user_login in the wp_users table so I can make a plugin that will display users' total scores.

**UPDATE:**
From the suggestion below, it appears the submitter_id is being created by the [uniqid function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) in PHP. Apparently, it's a unique string that reflects the current time.

So... the only thing to do now (I think) is to create a variable based on a mysql query that will retrieve the current logged in user's id and set that to the 'submitter_id.'

Comment: Take a look at the survey plugin's code, find where the `submitter_id` is generated and reverse that in your own plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin now works as I would like, with a little alteration. Instead of setting submitter_id to a random value, it is now set to the logged in user's id. This will allow displaying other users' answers. The + indicates new lines of code in the output_quiz.php file:

```
function wpss_getQuiz($quiz_id){
  global $wpdb;    
 + global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo();

<input type="hidden" name="quiz_id" value="'.$quiz['id'].'" />  
      +  <input type="hidden" name="submitter_id" value="'.$current_user->ID.'" />';
```

Thanks to [Johannes Pille](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/9745/johannes-pille) for the suggestion.